# Mulitiple selection of input:radio elements in one jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I have four RadioButtonList and I want to select input:radio from them. I use this code:

```
$("#<%=rblTipoviMKR.ClientID%> input:radio,#<%=rblTipoviMKD.ClientID%> input:radio,#<%=rblTipoviMKU.ClientID%> input:radio,#<%=rblTipoviMKV.ClientID%> input:radio").change(function (event) {
        checkTipRadio($(this).val());
    });
```

My question is, can I, and how, first set  and on the end of selector put input:radio for all four RadioLists? Something like this:

```
$("#<%=rblTipoviMKR.ClientID%>,#<%=rblTipoviMKD.ClientID%>,#<%=rblTipoviMKU.ClientID%> ,#<%=rblTipoviMKV.ClientID%> input:radio").change(function (event) {
        checkTipRadio($(this).val());
    });
```

but this will select only radio:input for rblTipoviMKV,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for that purpose:

```
$("#<%=rblTipoviMKR.ClientID%>, #<%=rblTipoviMKD.ClientID%>, "
    + "#<%=rblTipoviMKU.ClientID%>, #<%=rblTipoviMKV.ClientID%>")
.find("input:radio").change(function() {
    checkTipRadio($(this).val());
});
```

However, a more readable solution would be to decorate your four `rblTipovi` elements with a specific `class` attribute and match that class instead:

```
$(".yourRblClass input:radio").change(function() {
    checkTipRadio($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First select all lists and then filter them using `find`:

```
$("#<%=rblTipoviMKR.ClientID%>,#<%=rblTipoviMKD.ClientID%>,#<%=rblTipoviMKU.ClientID%> ,#<%=rblTipoviMKV.ClientID%>").find('input:radio').change(function (event) {
    checkTipRadio($(this).val());
});
```